# Alternative to "one thread per X" architecture?

Tags: php, ruby, multithreading, scalability

I have been told that I shouldn't be using "one thread per" anything aproach if I want my application to scale beyond "not so far", and that there were other architectures I should look into. Only I weren't told any of those architectures' names, and I couldn't find much on google.

Specifically I need this for a real-time web game, mostly chat-based. I would be using web sockets, but I need to process all the incoming events (many per second per game) concurrently fast enough.

If possible, I need this architecture to be viable in Ruby or PHP.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why Ruby or PHP? Node.js is built specifically for this.

Comment: @kitgui.com Because I only know a limited set of languages, and those are the ones that are server-side and well suited for the web =p. Yeah I like node's ideas, but I couldn't find a node web framework that is mature enough.

Comment: Since the original comment about 'better architectures' come out in a php post, I thought there was something I was missing in php. But maybe they were just talking about node.

Comment: Oh and there is also EventMachine which I don't fully understand yet but seems to be an alternative to threading, but that is for Ruby only.

Comment: @HappyDeveloper: Your logic is flawed IMHO, node is Javascript pretty similar to jQuery (which you must know of course). Also, node has a plethora of frameworks (just look into their GitHub wiki pages) and many of them are as powerful (or even more) and their PHP counterparts.

Comment: @AlixAxel I didn't say there weren't many of them, I said they weren't mature enough, which is understandable for the short time node has been around.

Comment: I don't think "many per second" should be a problem for any language you're using. Choose a language you're comfortable with, and you should do fine. It's when you're talking thousands+ per second that you might need to start thinking more seriously. Also if you're unsure, then build a simple prototype test server and bombard it with a similar testing client. You should quickly get an idea about what the framework/language/system can handle that way.

Comment: @Casper per second per game. What if there are 999 games running?

Comment: Well if it's chat-based..how many decisions per second can the humans make? I still doubt it's a problem. Run some tests, you'll learn something valuable about networking and processing as a bonus. It'll be good practice.

Comment: @Casper As I said it's a game, not just a chat. So you shouldn't make that sort of assumptions. And even when learning can be fun, I need to solve a real problem, not to reinvent the wheel and learn all the technologies available.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the APIs available to Ruby or php. If they can access the Win API and can be multi-threaded the recommended Windows functionality is that of IOCPs (I/O Completion Ports) that are connected to handles and sockets. One thread per available core usually works best to maximize scaling.